# Delete ALL Rest Apis in all regions, possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

Is there a way to delete all Rest APIs created in different regions, via AWS CLI?

I've created many of them, and it takes a long time to delete them manually via the GUI.

Comment: you can try boto3 script and use apigateway::delete_rest_api

Answer (score 0):

There is. You can write script with using
get-rest-apis
and
delete-rest-api
and something (e.g. jq) to extract rest-api-id from response of get-rest-apis
Make list of all regions and iterate. If there is some rest-api an this AWS accout that should not be deleted you need to take care about filtering ones you want to delete (it can be done with jq too)

See also:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/delete-rest-api.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same necessity and created a quick python script that executes shell commands  using awscli to fetch all regions, all ApiGateway APIs in each region and then deletes all of them one by one taking advantage of the fact that the 1 request per minute limit is applied per region.

[[Github Gist] Delete all ApiGateway APIs in all regions](https://gist.github.com/jpdom/cc693afbc9312f8946b877308bf437a9)